# How do I find the time of last typed word in Microsoft Word?

Tags: vba, time, ms-word

In Excel, you can find out when the last entry was made in a particular cell using VBA coding.
I was wondering whether in Word you can do the same as well.

I particularly want to know the time and date it was last entered.

Answer (score 0):

In Word, you can't get the time a particular Word was entered into the document. What you can get is the last time the file has been saved:

```
Sub PrintLastSaveTime()
    Dim propLastSaved As DocumentProperty
    Dim propLastAuthor As DocumentProperty

    Set propLastSaved = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(WdBuiltInProperty.wdPropertyTimeLastSaved)
    Set propLastAuthor = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(WdBuiltInProperty.wdPropertyLastAuthor)

    Debug.Print "The document was last saved by " & propLastAuthor.Value & " at "; propLastSaved.Value

End Sub
```